# Difference between var->myProperty and var.myProperty

Tags: objective-c, class, variables, object, properties

I am new in objective c and I have some doubts. I've seen that you can access to the properties of a class like **var->myProperty** and like that too **variable.myProperty**, but I do not know what the difference between the 2. I searched a lot in internet and really have not found a conclusive answer.

Sorry if I have spelling errors, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `obj->foo` syntax accesses the ivar `foo` of `obj` whereas `obj.foo` accesses the property (defined by `@property`). The main difference is that `obj->foo` does not use any getters/setters and writes to the ivar directly.

For example, if you defined the property like this

```
@property (atomic, strong, readonly) SomeClass *foo;
```

Modern Objective-C compilers will automatically create an ivar `_foo` and the property `foo` for you (without the need of declaring the ivar and `@synthesize`ing the property.

`obj.foo` will then automatically use the `atomic` getter and will make the property `readonly` (ie no setter). Using the ivar syntax `obj->_foo`, you are reading the property non-atomically(!) and you can even write it (remember, the property is `readonly`!).

Usually it's very easy: Always use the property syntax, except in `init` and `dealloc`, there you use the ivar syntax. Obviously when you are actually implementing a getter or a setter yourself, that's another place to use the ivar syntax. (thanks to @godel9). (Remember: That's a rough guideline, there are other use-cases where you might want direct ivar access).

*EDIT*: Because of some critique in the comments: It's true that the dot syntax can also be used without declaring something as `@property`, eg some use `array.count` instead of `[array count]` (for `NSArray *array`). But given that the OP asked about properties vs ivars, that was certainly not asked. Also note that for a given `@property ... SomeClass *foo` the ivar is not necessarily `_foo` but that's would be the auto-generated ivar name in recent ObjC compilers (with `@synthesize` you can map properties to arbitrary ivars).

Comment: The other place to use ivar syntax is custom getters and setters.

Comment: Obviously true, adding that.

Comment: There are a number of errors in this answer; ivar access should be used in init/dealloc and not anywhere else.   The ivar, in this case, would be `_foo`, unless explicitly synthesized otherwise.  There is no requirement that the dot syntax only be used with `@property`.

Comment: @bbum Don't you also need to use ivar access in custom getters and setters to avoid an infinite loop?

Comment: @BradAllred `self->ivar` does _NOT_ prevent `self` from being retained in a block.

Comment: @bbum 1.) The `foo` vs `_foo` was a simple typo (as you could see in other places of my answer), corrected that. 2.) Nowhere did I state that the dot syntax can only be used with `@property`s

Comment: @godel9 Obviously true what you say but as now also written in the answer: It was meant as a rough guideline not as a complete guide. There are other use cases where you need or might want ivar syntax outside of getter/setters/init/dealloc.

Comment: @JohannesWeiß you misunderstood what i meant (and i see my comment was unclear so i deleted it). What I meant is if you have an ivar that is *not* accessible via a property and you need to use it in a "weakself" situation then you will need to use `weakself->ivar` since just using `ivar` will retain self.

Comment: Since I deleted my previous comment I should restate that properties handle KVO notifications for you. A very important for Cocoa due to bindings, still noteworthy for UIKit too.

Answer (score 3):

There are three cases to consider:

- use of `someObject.something`
- use of `self->something`
- use of `otherObject->something`

`someObject.something` is the *dot syntax*.   It is exactly equivalent to `[someObject something]` in terms of behavior.  It is a method call.   Note that `something` does not have to be declared via an `@property`.  That is, `someArray.count` or `someString.length` are both syntactically valid.

`self->something` is accessing an ivar directly.  It is a very rarely used syntax;  rare is in *pretty much never*.  Instead, just access the ivar directly using `something =` or `[something doSomething]`.   No need for the `->`.

`otherObject->something` is grubbing around `otherObject`'s instance variables directly.  Bad programmer.  No donut.  Don't do that.  It breaks encapsulation and leads to extremely fragile, hard to maintain, code.

---

A note on `@property` declarations.  If you have:

```
 @property (atomic, strong, readonly) SomeClass *foo;
```

And if you let the compiler automatically `@synthesize` everything, it will create an instance variable named `_foo`.

You should use direct access in your `init` and `dealloc` methods, but -- typically, though not always -- use the setter/getter everywhere else.  I.e. in your `init` you would do `_foo = [SomeClass someClassWithSomeMagicValue:42]` (assumes ARC, so no `retain` needed).  Everywhere else, you would do `[[self foo] castMagic];`.

Comment: The last two cases are the same case.

Comment: @newacct Not quite;  the 2nd case does not break encapsulation in that it is accessing the instance variable of the instance that is executing the method.  In the 3rd case, the code would be accessing the iVar of some *other* object, breaking encapsulation.

Comment: but that's not a language concept. It's just a programming style issue.

Comment: @newacct It is way beyond a programmings style issue.  Breaking encapsulation in a dynamic language like ObjC has a huge cost;  it breaks subclassing, categories, KVO, etc.etc.etc...  If you were to do `self->`, someone looking at your code might wrinkle an eyebrow and move on.  If you were to do `otherObject->`, that same person would likely be knocking at your door in a heartbeat expecting an explanation as to why your are undermining a standard encapsulation idiom of the language.

Comment: It's not uncommon in Java.

Comment: @newacct This isn't Java. :)  It is beyond uncommon in Objective-C;  it is an anti-pattern and use of it will draw ire from any seasoned ObjC programmer.   When Java was derived from ObjC, the pattern was considered passable in ObjC.  That changed in the mid '90s as the realization of how fragile & rigid direct access made the resulting codebase.

Answer (score 0):

look at Pointers in objective-c
http://www.drdobbs.com/mobile/pointers-in-objective-c/225700236